# Cygwin -Windows Unable to initialize device PRN

Tags: windows, shell, cygwin

I am executing shell scripts on windows command prompt by making bash as the default application to open .sh files. I am able to run any script without input parameters , but for those scripts with input parameters I get the error "Unable to initialize device PRN". I can see that the parameters are not being passed to the script. How can I pass an argument to the shell script from windows command line?

This is what I am doing in the command prompt.

```
X:> OracleSPExec.sh Procedure Database
PROCEDURE=
export PROCEDURE
DATABASE=
export DATABASE
```

Answer (score 14):

it seems that the shell script uses `print` command/builtin, which may conflict with windows `print.exe` which prints file to `PRN`: device.

Answer (score 2):

I'm running into this problem, trying to run some locally-invented tagging scripts that used to work but I have a new laptop and it's running Windows 10. The *bash* in the version of cygwin that I installed doesn't seem to have `print` as a built-in command (it does have `printenv` and `printf` as external commands) and there is no `print` command other than the one in `System32`:

```
$ type print
print is hashed (/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/system32/print)

$ type echo
echo is a shell builtin
```

As a work-around, I added this line near the top of each script:

```
alias print=echo
```

And that eliminated the "Unable to initialize device PRN" problem. It would still be nice to know why this worked at one point.

Answer (score 1):

Two possible issues:

1. Missing shebang `#!`

You must add this line at the beginning of your script:

```
 #!/usr/bin/bash
```

2. Unicode BOM at the beginning of the file

Sometime if the file is written in UTF-8 with BOM the shebang cannot be interpreted. Remove the heading (hidden?) characters in front of your shebang.